# what is CLOUDINARY_DEFAULT_URL AND CLOUDINARY_DEFAULT_PUBLICID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern, cloudinary

my user sign up page need this 2

[my .env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NEe6.png)

my signup controller is

```
const User = require('../model/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { uploadToCloudinary } = require('../utils/cloudinary');

const handleNewUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, user, email, pwd, picture } = req.body;
  let url, publicId;

  if (!name || !user || !email || !pwd) return res.status(400).json('Something is missing');

  if (!picture) {
    url = process.env.CLOUDINARY_DEFAULT_URL;
    publicId = process.env.CLOUDINARY_DEFAULT_PUBLIC_ID;
  }

  const duplicateUser = await User.findOne({ username: user }).exec();
  if (duplicateUser) return res.sendStatus(409).json('Username taken'); // Conflict

  const duplicateEmail = await User.findOne({ email }).exec();
  if (duplicateEmail) return res.sendStatus(409).json('Email taken'); // Conflict

  try {
    const hashedPwd = await bcrypt.hash(pwd, 10);

    if (picture) {
      const uploadedResponse = await uploadToCloudinary(picture, 'Profiles');
      url = uploadedResponse.url;
      publicId = uploadedResponse.public_id;
    }

    await User.create({
      name,
      username: user,
      email,
      picture: {
        url,
        publicId,
      },
      password: hashedPwd,
    });

    res.status(201).json(`New user named ${user} was created!`);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err.message);
  }
};

module.exports = { handleNewUser };
```

without this 2 i get error in sign up page if some one need more information to answer me please ask in comment section . i really need this answer thank you

this is the error massage in vs code console

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYf1d.png)

this is error massage

```
POST /posts
{
  message: 'Stale request - reported time is 2022-12-10 01:50:51 +0000 which is more than 1 hour ago',
  name: 'Error',
  http_code: 400
}
C:\Users\atii\Desktop\project\Dev to\( $$ Backend ++ Front End $$ )\Devto-clone-main\server\controllers\postsController.js:19
  const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(file, 'Posts');
          ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'url' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
    at createPost (C:\Users\atii\Desktop\project\Dev to\( $$ Backend ++ Front End $$ )\Devto-clone-main\server\controllers\postsController.js:19:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v19.2.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

here is my post controller that have same error :

```
const Post = require('../model/Post');
const User = require('../model/User');
const Tag = require('../model/Tag');
const Comment = require('../model/Comment');
const cloudinary = require('../config/cloudinary');
const { uploadToCloudinary } = require('../utils/cloudinary');
const { getPostParams, unCapitalizeFirstLetter } = require('../helpers/string');
const { createTags, updateTags, deleteTags } = require('./tagsController');
const {
  likeNotification,
  removeLikeNotification,
  postNotification,
  removePostNotification,
} = require('./notificationsController');

const createPost = async (req, res) => {
  const { title, file, body, tags, authorUsername } = req.body;

  const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(file, 'Posts');
  const author = await User.findOne({ username: authorUsername }).exec();

  const formattedTags = tags
    .trim()
    .split(',')
    .map(w => w.trim().replace(/ /g, '-'));

  const createdPost = await Post.create({
    title,
    image: { url, publicId },
    body,
    author: author._id,
  });

  author.followers.map(followerId => {
    (async () => {
      await postNotification(author._id, createdPost._id, followerId);
    })();
  });

  await createTags(formattedTags, createdPost);

  author.posts.push(createdPost._id);

  await author.save();

  res.status(200).json(createdPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const getPost = async (req, res) => {
  const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
  const authorId = await author?.toObject({ getters: true }).id;

  const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

  const foundPost = await Post.findOne({
    author: authorId,
    title: postTitle,
    _id: postId,
  })
    .populate('author')
    .populate('comments')
    .populate('tags')
    .exec();

  res.status(200).json(foundPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;

  const posts = await Post.find(userId ? { bookmarks: userId } : {})
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .populate('author')
    .populate('tags');
  if (!posts) res.status(204).json('No posts found');

  res.status(200).json(posts.map(post => post.toObject({ getters: true })));
};

const updatePost = async (req, res) => {
  const authorId = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
  const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

  const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(req.body.image.url, 'Posts');

  await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(req.body.image.publicId);

  req.body.image = { url, publicId };
  const formattedTags = req.body.tags
    .trim()
    .split(',')
    .map(w => w.trim().replace(/ /g, '-'));

  const post = await Post.findOne({
    author: authorId,
    title: postTitle,
    _id: postId,
  })
    .populate('author')
    .populate('tags');

  Object.keys(req.body).map(key => {
    if (key !== 'tags') post[key] = req.body[key];
  });

  await updateTags(formattedTags, post);

  await post.save();

  res.status(200).json(post.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const deletePostsByUserId = async user => {
  const { _id: userId } = user;

  user.comments.forEach(commentId => {
    (async () => {
      await Post.updateMany({ comments: commentId }, { $pull: { comments: commentId } });
    })();
  });

  const posts = await Post.find({ author: userId }).populate('tags');

  ['likes', 'unicorns', 'bookmarks'].forEach(k => {
    (async () => {
      await Post.updateMany({ [k]: userId }, { $pull: { [k]: userId } });
    })();
  });

  posts.forEach(post => {
    (async () => {
      await deleteTags(
        post.tags.map(({ name }) => name),
        post,
        true
      );
      await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(post.image.publicId);
      await Post.deleteOne({ _id: post._id });
    })();
  });

  await Comment.deleteMany({ author: userId });
};

const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
  const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
  const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

  await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(req.body.publicId);

  const foundPost = await Post.findOne({
    author: author._id,
    title: postTitle,
    _id: postId,
  })
    .populate('tags')
    .exec();

  if (!foundPost) return res.sendStatus(204);

  const comments = await Comment.find({ parentPost: postId }).populate({
    path: 'author',
    populate: 'followers',
  });

  comments.forEach(({ author }) =>
    (async () => {
      author.comments.forEach(comment => author.comments.pull(comment));
    })()
  );
  author.posts.pull(postId);
  await author.save();

  await Comment.deleteMany({ parentPost: postId });

  await deleteTags(
    foundPost.tags.map(({ name }) => name),
    foundPost,
    true
  );

  removePostNotification(author._id, foundPost._id, author.followers);

  await Post.deleteOne({ _id: foundPost._id });

  res.status(200).json(foundPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const postReaction = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.body;
  const { action, postUrl } = req.params;
  const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(postUrl);
  const isUndoing = action.includes('remove');
  const actionKey = isUndoing
    ? unCapitalizeFirstLetter(action.replace('remove', '')) + 's'
    : action + 's';

  const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
  const authorId = await author.toObject({ getters: true }).id;

  const updatedPost = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
    { author: authorId, title: postTitle, _id: postId },
    isUndoing ? { $pull: { [actionKey]: userId } } : { $addToSet: { [actionKey]: userId } },
    { new: true, timestamps: false }
  );

  if (isUndoing) await removeLikeNotification(userId, updatedPost._id, authorId);
  else await likeNotification(userId, updatedPost._id, authorId);

  res.status(200).json(updatedPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

module.exports = {
  createPost,
  getPosts,
  getPost,
  updatePost,
  deletePost,
  deletePostsByUserId,
  postReaction,
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't need these two environment variables. Could you please update your question to include the error message you get from Cloudinary when you try to upload after removing those 2 environment variables from your .env file? In addition, could you please provide more information as to where you got those environment variable names from? They are not expected/required from a Cloudinary perspective.

Comment: @aleksandar  I really  happy u answered me . first of all thank you u spend time to answered me  ok  I will include the error massage . please wait for me i will send the error . because error not showing always . i have to find error .

Comment: @Aleksandar i add the error massage picture to my question body . can u see please

Answer (score 0):

Getting the "Stale request" error usually means that either your server/computer's time/clock is in the past, the timezone is not the right one or the `timestamp` (used as part of the upload request) was not calculated in GMT.

If you're using one of [Cloudinary's Backend SDKs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudinary_sdks#backend) to perform the upload, then the Upload method would automatically send the 'timestamp' as part of the upload request, so if the local time on your server/computer is in the past, the request will not be able to be validated.

It would be worth double-checking that the time and timezone configured on your computer or server you are running this from is the correct one for your location. You can try to run the below in the terminal and check the current time it reports and compare that with what the time of the location of your computer/server should be -

```
date && date +%s
```